# JS Image Upload Failure OSX Localhost

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, macos

I have a site that has a basic image upload. It is executed by JS code. I can post the code here, but it is quite extensive; so I refrain for now. When I try to upload, it works normally and the progress bar runs an appropriate amount of time. However, when I inspect the entries in the MySQL DB's "photos" table, I find that the entries are created there, but most of their fields are NULL. In particular, fields containing the file path and temporary file path are empty.

Does this sound like a permission problem? I am running a basic Mac setup with out-of-the-box Apache and services. I also have some virtual hosts configured but am unsure of whether the affect anything. What else can be causing this?

**Edit**: Here is the HTML of the form that has user controls for the upload.

```
<div class="fileUploadForm" id="fileUploadForm-Device">

<div>

    <h3>Upload Photos</h3>

     <p id="deviceFilesDropZone"><span id="drag-drop-text">DRAG AND DROP YOUR PHOTOS HERE</span> <br /><span id="deviceFilesInfo" style="display: none;">0 photos</span><br /><span class="btn" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px;">Browse Photos</span></p>

    <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="uploadLoadingBar" id="uploadLoadingBar"><div class="bar"></div><p id="uploadProgressText"></p></div>
    </div>

    <p style="display: none;"><input id="filePicker" type="file" accept="image/*" name="filePicker" multiple /></p>

    <hr />

    </div>
</div>
```

There is also the following declaration in the `<script>` section right below:

```
var target = document.getElementById("deviceFilesDropZone");

var deviceFiles = new Array();
var totalDeviceFileSize = 0;
var totalDeviceBytesUploaded = 0;
var deviceUploadStartTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var currentTempStatusIndex  = 0;
target.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

As you can see, I tried adding the set for enctype and the same problem still persists.

Comment: Uploaded files don't usually keep the path information; it would be a security concern.  But you can make a code that isn't very extensive to investigate that issue.

Comment: Most of the other files in DB keep the path. I just inherited this code and am trying to work through it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your form has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"

It sounds like that is the cause

Comment: Do you mean the form that selects the photos from the hard drive?

Comment: Yes @ArtforLife If you upload photos , a regular form will not be able to stream the image to your server. So you need to take provisions to help the form out. This you do by adding the enctype.

The form then looks something like this.

    <form action="someurl" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>

Comment: See the code above for the type of form I have. I do not seem to have the html form.

Comment: A dropzone is not a basic upload form. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: By plugin do you mean JS framework? IF so, here are some that I saw. Not all of them may be relevant to the upload feature:

jQuery, Scrollbox, conversion_async, serve.